# css3 transition on load

Tags: jquery, css, onload

I try to create a css3 transition effect on my page but i need to transition start on load with jquery so i write this:

```
#igrac1 {
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color:#FFF;  
  border-radius:5px;  
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-color:#F00;
}
.css {
    background:#000000;
}

    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#igrac1')
        .css({"opacity":0})   // Set to 0 as soon as possible – may result in flicker, but it's not hidden for users with no JS (Googlebot for instance!)
        .delay(200)           // Wait for a bit so the user notices it fade in
        .css({"opacity":1});  // Fade it back in. Swap css for animate in legacy browsers if required.
});

</script>
```

and offcource:

```
<div id="igrac1" class="css"></div>
```

in body tag... but no working on load. WHY is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#igrac1').fadeOut(10).delay(200).fadeIn();
```

You can also try this:

```
.css {
    background:  #000000;
    display: none;
}
```

and then

```
$('#igrac1').fadeIn();
```

Comment: @PeterWeb make a fiddle and give that

Comment: @PeterWeb do you testing in live server or in localhost. check that you include the jQuery library and other credentials.

Comment: on localhost but with latest library     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @PeterWeb do you place your `$(document).ready()` after jQuery load `script` code?

Comment: i place just this: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$('#igrac1').fadeIn();
</script>

Comment: @PeterWeb Please place `<script type="text/javascript"> $('#igrac1').fadeIn(); </script>` before `</body>` tag and test

Answer (score 0):

add `display:none;` to the id. then `fadeIn()`, see working example

http://jsfiddle.net/efortis/UfTQd/

```
#igrac1 {
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    border:2px solid;
    border-color:#FFF;  
    border-radius:5px;  
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    background-color:#F00;

    /*note this line*/ display:none;
}​


$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#igrac1').fadeIn();    
});​
```